# mod_rewrite: app1 to app1/ and app2 to app2/

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm new to mod_rewrite, but I have successfully set up an Apache 2.4 Reverse Proxy (doesn't use `<directory>`). However, now I need to redirect two literal paths (app1 and app2 to app1/ and app2/):

```
https://external.com/app1 to https://internal.com/app1/ (with the slash)
https://external.com/app2 to https://internal.com/app2/ (with the slash)
```

where app1/ and app2/ are

```
ProxyPass                "/app1/" "https://internal.com/app1/"
ProxyPassReverse         "/app1/" "https://internal.com/app1/"

ProxyPass                "/app2/" "https://internal.com/app2/"
ProxyPassReverse         "/app2/" "https://internal.com/app2/"
```

I've tried variations on these, but they cause loops or otherwise don't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(app1)$ $1/ [PT]
RewriteRule ^/(app2)$ $1/ [PT]
```

Thoughts? Again, I don't know mod_rewrite well.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with `redirect` instead of `mod_rewrite`:

```
Redirect /app1   /app1/
Redirect /app2   /app2/
```